# Summation of the squares of the coefficients of the original sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I was wondering if it is possible to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2x^n$
given $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = f(x).$

I am aware that $$ (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n)^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k} $$ but I do not see now how to extract the square of $a_k$ for some $k$. And there seem to be squares there only for even $n$.
How do I find the sum up top?

Comment: $a^n$ and $a_n$ have different meanings.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: So there were 2 typos. Corrected them both, sorry again. It's supposed to be $a_n$ in all cases.

Comment: Do you  have some specific $a_i$ in mind?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420397) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795061).